# Prevent DOM tampering and modifications

Tags: javascript, dom

I wonder whether it is possible to somehow "lock out" the DOM once it is created and make sure that JavaScript could not further modify it.

The purpose is to preserve the integrity of a webpage.

I believe it is impossible but still hope that maybe somebody has an interesting idea.

Comment: I think it is impossible.. you can't control the client side.

Comment: no, in short this isn't possible, some people try security through obscurity by attempting to lock out the console for example, but this won't deter experienced hackers, as there's no sure fire way... after all the page is rendered on the client side as @StarsSky mentions, so can be manipulated any way the client wants in reality.

Comment: Nonetheless, you might want to look into [Content Security Policy](https://content-security-policy.com/) to shield your site/app from as many known attack vectors as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer as it was already said by @Stu: no, it isn't possible.

Let's make the disclaimer come first: I have been researching over the last 3
years about DOM based attacks such as the ones called Man-in-the-Browser (MitB).
The company where I do R&D is focused on Web Application integrity.

As you can't "lock out" the DOM the best you can do is to restrict what can
access and change it: as @CBroes said you can start with [Content Security Policy (CSP)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) so that your server can
instruct the browser what script/styles sources are allowed.

CSP purpose can be defeated by anything that can strip HTTP headers or `meta`
tags from the HTTP response prior to browser parsing e.g. MitB trojan.

[Subresources Integrity (SRI)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity) allows you to tell to the browser "hey, I want this
resource if and only if its current hash matches this one". You should provide
the hash you know using the `integrity` attribute. This is great specially if
you're loading resources from remote locations like CDNs: if they get
compromised and the script you're loading is added a malicious payload, your application will get compromised.

As for CSP, for example a MitB trojan will be able to strip these attributes
prior to Browser parsing, nevertheless using SRI you're raising the bar.

Accepting the fact that web pages can change legitimately or by interference of
something running in the execution environment, allow us (and my R&D) to go to
the next level: real time knowledge about DOM tampering and the capability to 
distinguish between "self-inflicted" and malicious/undesired tampering.

My R&D is already a step further and I would be glad to share it with you but
on a side channel as it can be wrongly perceived in this thread context.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you can watch DOM with mutationObserver API and prevent/revert DOM changes.

That's what I'm trying to do now, if someone will be interested can you make(did I make) it work, let me know

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="target-node"></div>
```

Although it is possible to do so, it does not prevent people familiar with js from changing the DOM

```js
const options = {
  childList: true,
  attributes: true,
  subtree: true,
  attributesOldValue: true,
  characterData: true,
  characterDataOldValue: true,
}

const targetNode = document.querySelector('.target-node')
const childrenDom = `<div class="watermark">Watermark, Change me!</div>`
targetNode.innerHTML = childrenDom

function reset(expression = () => {}) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    observer.disconnect()
    expression()
    observer.observe(targetNode, options)
  }, 0)
}

function callback(records) {
  const record = records[0]
  console.log(' / record', record)
  reset(() => {
    targetNode.innerHTML = childrenDom
  })
}

const observer = new MutationObserver(callback)
observer.observe(h1, options)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create some hash function that takes DOM elements (presumably in string form) as its input, and then check your "locked" DOM elements against an API endpoint that computes the hash. Check that the hash is the expected value. If it is not the expected value, the DOM element has been tampered with.